# How to observe objects in response JSON with no specyfic names in RXJS Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, observable, formattable

Situation looks like this. 
I need to fill mat-table dynamically after receiving a response from API. In response JSON there are those anonymous json objects in json array "files".

```
"files": [
      {
        "title": "dummy",
        "link": "https://t1.mogree.com/backmeister_content/pdfs/presentation/31347009705473837693867181531764_a.pdf",
        "attachment": "dummy-atachment_name.pdf",
        "userTypes": [
          "ADM",
          "INT"
        ],
        "itemid": "31347009705473837693867181531764_a.pdf",
        "type": 17,
        "itemproviderid": 0,
        "detailtype": 0
      },
      {
        "title": "dummy",
        "link": "https://t1.mogree.com/backmeister_content/pdfs/presentation/46728595498675807527841664269653_a.pdf",
        "attachment": "dummy-atachment_name.pdf",
        "userTypes": [
          "ADM",
          "INT"
        ],
        "itemid": "46728595498675807527841664269653_a.pdf",
        "type": 17,
        "itemproviderid": 0,
        "detailtype": 0
      }
```

I dont know how to set observable on this imtems of this table. I just getting "files" item. I need to have access to those anonymous objects. 
For now my function with request looks like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getAttachments()
      .map(data => data['detailresponse'])
      .map(data => data['files'])
      .subscribe(files => {
          });
  }
```

I need access to fields: "title", "link", "itemId".
Maybe i need second observable inside subscribe()??

Comment: You are getting files as an array, couldn't you just use it in your function? Also on what basis you need to filter the files?

Comment: I don't see `detailresponse`

Comment: @Explosion Pills 2 detailresponse is higher in hierarchy in this JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and let me know if it works!

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.apiService.getAttachments()
      .map(data => data['detailresponse'])
      .map(data => data['files'])
      .subscribe(files => {
          files.forEach(file => {
              console.log(file.title, file.link, file. itemId);
          });
      });
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assume your service returns a JSON object array. Within your subscription function, you need to iterate over it as a general array and then parse it.

```
this.api.getAttachments()
   .subscribe( data => {
            data.files.forEach(file => { 
                          console.log(file.title, file.link, file.itemId)
```

An easy way to identify the structure is to place a debugger in the subscribe call, and see the object hierarchy by expanding it in the dev console. Then you can base your parsing on that hierarchy.